# LINQ difference OrderBy x.field descending versus OrderByDescending(x=>x.field)

Tags: linq, database-performance

In order to make pagination, I need to order a query list, then take nSize elements skipping nFrom first

I wonder if, from the performance point of view, it's the same ordering by the clause orderby in the query, like this

```
IList<Product> resul = (
  from m in db.Products()
  where m.CategoryId==cId
  orderby m.Name descending
  select m
).Skip(nFrom).Take(nSize).ToList();
```

or ordering the results, like this

```
IList<Product> resul = (
  from m in db.Products()
  where m.CategoryId==cId
  select m
).OrderByDescending(m=>m.Name).Skip(nFrom).Take(nSize).ToList();
```

I guess LINQ makes the same in both cases, but I need make sure in order to use the second option so I can parameterize the order field.

Comment: Both queries are identical.

Comment: i think, you can do it like this too : `IList<Product> resul = db.Products.Where(m => m.CategoryId == cId).OrderByDescending(m => m.Name).Skip(nFrom).Take(nSize).ToList();`

Comment: Using something like LINQPad, you can see the lambda translation of your query syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I used LinkqPad and checked it's the same. Please, vote my question up so any other user can find it easier.